# Is it possible to share header file only with a cc_test target?

Tags: unit-testing, header-files, bazel, build-system

Say I have a package with a single `cc_library` target and an inner package for tests with a single `cc_test` target as follows:

```
mylib/
     BUILD
     mylib.h
     mylib.c
     mylib-private.h
     tests/
         BUILD
         test.c
```

In order to perform some unit-tests I need access to "private" methods, so I created `mylib-private.h` which I want to include only in the test code.
Obviously this header should not be part of the library API and should not be shipped with it.

If I add `mylib-private` to the `hdrs` of `mylib` - It'll be visible to all.
If I add `mylib-private` to `srcs` of `mylib` - only `mylib` can use it...

Is there a way to control the visibility of a single header file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what is the official recommended pattern here, but I ended up inclduing both `mylib` and `mylib-tests` in the same package, and then they could both add `mylib-private` to their `srcs` attribute:

BUILD:

```
cc_library(
    name="mylib",
    hdrs=["mylib.h",],
    srcs=[
        "mylib.c",
        "mylib-private.h"
    ]
)

cc_test(
    name="mylib-tests",
    srcs=glob([
        "tests/*.c",
        "mylib-private.h"
    ]),
    deps=[
        "//:mylib"
    ]
)
```

And the structure:

```
mylib/
     BUILD
     mylib.h
     mylib.c
     mylib-private.h
     tests/
         test.c
```